# Drake "desired_state" input port has size 0

Tags: drake

I'm getting this error: "RuntimeError: System::FixInputPortTypeCheck(): expected value of type drake::systems::BasicVector with size=0 for input port 'kuka.desired_state' (index 0) ..."

I can't figure out why the size of input port 'kuka.desired_state' is 0 (I expect it to be 6, for the 6 joints of my robot arm). Going through the drake source code, I've traced the problem down to `actuator.has_controller()` returning False for all the actuators (but `plant.num_actuators()` returns 6). Is there an explicit way to add a controller for an actuator? How do I resolve this error?

My URDF file has 6 "revolute"  tags and 6  tags. Here is a snippet from the URDF:

```
    <joint name="arm_a1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="6.9388939039072276073e-18 1.0408340855860842566e-17 0.16999995708465576172"
            rpy="-3.141592653589793116 1.7783981468004833182e-49 1.570796326794896336" />
        <parent link="arm_base" />
        <child link="arm_a1" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
        <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-3.05432619099" upper="3.05432619099" />
        <joint_properties friction="0.0" />
    </joint>
    ... repeat for all 6 joints

    <transmission name="tran_a1">
        <robotNamespace>/kuka</robotNamespace>
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="arm_a1">
            <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor_a1">
            <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
            <drake:gear_ratio value="160.0" />
            <drake:rotor_inertia value="0.0001321" />
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    ... repeat for all 6 joints
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another helpful hint was that the "desired_state" port in the diagram was greyed out, indicating it has dimension 0:

["desired_state" port greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S0Jj.png)

While I'm not sure why this was, I switched to using `ForceDriver` as the model driver for the robot arm (in the scenario YAML). Doing this opened a "actuation" InputPort for my HardwareStation which has dimension 6, as expected. (I was previously using `JointStiffnessDriver`). I then added an `InverseDynamicsController` to the DiagramBuilder, and connected the "generalized_force" output of the `InverseDynamicsController` to the "actuation" InputPort. Then I can control the "desired_state" (which contains both desired joint positions and velocities) and "desired_acceleration" InputPorts of the `InverseDynamicsController` to make the arm move. This was the solution that worked for me.

Although I did not try this, this other solution was recommended to me by a drake developer: "there is a relatively new feature where you can have the MultibodyPlant perform PD control internally, where you command a state on the input port and it uses an internal "implicit" PD controller to derive a actuation torque from that desire.  That's what the "desired_state" input port is for.  There's basically no good demos of that yet that I can find.  You can grep around for set_controller_gains (in code) and/or drake:controller_gains (in SDFormat files) for whatever we have."